# 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

El siguiente error se me da cuando trato de reenviar un correo con laravel, como tal ya tengo todo hecho pero las rutas como que no las esta tomando, ejemplo 
esta es la ruta

```
Route::post('/renviar','MailController@reenvio');
```

es la ruta para el renvio, 
el metodo de reenvio es el siguiente

```
public function reenvio(Request $request){
  $subject = $request->input('subject');
  $e_mail = $request->input('Emails');  
  $estipulo = $request->input('plantillas');

  $text = $request->input('editor1');
  $files = $request->input('adjunto');
  foreach ($e_mail as $key) {
      Mail::send('emails.envia',array(
           'key'   =>  $key,
           'subject' => $subject,
           'text'    =>  $text,
           'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
           'files'  =>  $files,

      ),
      function($msj)use($key,$estipulo,$text,$subject,$files){
          $msj->subject($subject);
          $msj->to($key);
          if($files) {
            foreach ($files as $attachment) {
              $msj->attach(public_path('/storage/boletines/').$attachment, [
                          'as' => $attachment,
                          'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                  ]);    
            }
          }

      });
  }      

  return Redirect::to('/Admin/reportes/create');
 }
```

el se encarga de enviar el correo 
y esta es la vista,

```
@section('menu2')
  <div id="menu2" style="display: block; width: 90%; height: 180%; opacity: 1; float: left;">  
{{ csrf_field() }}
<br>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<form class="form-group" method="POST"  name="formNombre" action="/renviar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="clientes">
        <div class="titulo">



          Panel de Control


        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="func" value="ActualizarCliente">
        <input type="hidden" id="cliente-id" name="cliente-id" value="62">

        <div class="datos">
           <div id="clientes" class="tipos">
        <div class="titulo">
          Buscar
           <img class="boton-buscar icon" title="Buscar Clientes" onclick="Busqueda('busqueda-clientes', 'buscar-clientes', 'clientes', true)" src="{{ URL::asset('images/search2.png') }}">
          </div>

          <div class="busqueda" id="busqueda-clientes">
          <div class="buscador fa fa-search input">
            <input type="search" title="Digite al Cliente"  id="buscar-clientes" placeholder="Buscar Cliente">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>

        <br>
        <div class="scroll" style="height:95%;overflow: auto;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
               <tbody id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
                <th>Seleccion</th>
                <th>Clientes enviados</th>
                <th>Archivos enviados</th>
            <th>Grupos </th>
            <th>Emails</th>
            <th>Plantilla</th>
            <th>Fecha Subido</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($historica as $his)
                  @foreach($clients as $clien)
                  @if($clien->id == $his->cliente_id)
                  <tr>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="{{$his->id}}" ></td>
                      <td>{{$clien->nombre}} <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="nombre" value="{{$clien->nombre}}"> </td>
                      <td>{{$his->titulo}} <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="titulo" value="{{$his->titulo}}"> </td>
                      <td>{{$his->grupo}} <input type="text"  hidden="hidden" name="grupo" value="{{$his->grupo}}"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="Emails"  value="{{$his->emails}}"></td>
                      <td>{{$his->texto}} <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="text" value="{{$his->texto}}"> <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="firma" value="{{$his->firma}}"></td>
                      <td>{{$his->calendario}} <input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="fecha" value="{{$his->calendario}}"> </td>
                      <td><a href="/storage/boletines/{{$his->link}}" target="_blank"  frameborder="0"><img src="/images/ojo.png" title="visualizar"></a><input type="text" name="link" hidden="hidden" value="{{$his->link}}">
                        <button type="submit" >Renviar</button>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div> 
         </div>
         <br>

         <br>

           <br>
            </div>
             <div class="datos-botones">

     </div>

       </div>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

el problema es que cuando le doy click en la tabla para renviar el correo, se me da el error del titulo, y si trato de hacer otra pagina y redirecionarlarlo a esa pagina me tira el mismo error que estoy haciendo mal, no se si es que en el form, o la forma en la que muestro las cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el problema es que el campo CRSF está fuera del formulario, para que funcione debe estar dentro del formulario:

```
<form class="form-group" method="POST"  name="formNombre" action="/renviar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="clientes">
    <div class="titulo">
```

Comment: era eso, suponia que algo puse mal, gracias